# prerender io - not working in production while doing fine in staging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, prerender

Im using `prerender.io` in `my node.js` app to have correct SEO.
Im working with `codeanywhere.com` for staging and a `digital ocean droplet` for production app. both setups are identical (`ubuntu 14.04, node -v v0.10.25`)

Sharing link from my staging page on facebook results in displaying the rendered meta data as expected: title, description and image. This means that everything worked as data are coming from JS database api calls.

I then installed everything on my production droplet, and it's not working as it should. sharing the same link results in displaying only my droplet ip address.

Im not using any domain name right now, but I can't think of it as an issue. anyone faced this issue before? It's my first time with prerender.io so if anyone could help me figure out how to test is everything is correct it would be nice.

I can provide code if anything is relevant for you guys.
the tutorial I followed was this one https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io

Comment: Are you running your own prerender server or are you using our hosted Prerender.io service? If you are using an IP address, you'll need to set up a domain name and use that to get it to work.

Comment: are you saying that url such as xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888/path/url/ won't work?
Im using service I think, I followed the tutorial listed above. prerender.io dashboard is displaying cached page from my staging, but nothing from my production droplet.

Comment: Correct. You'll need a domain name that is resolvable through DNS for it to work through our hosted service.